# Python2.7 + MySQL query with variable column return variable value

Tags: python, mysql

I'm try send this query:

```
    data = ('name')
    query = ("SELECT %s FROM table")

    cursor.execute(query,[data])
```

and print int:

```
b = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in b:
        a = row[0]
        list_of_a.append(model)
    return list_of_a

    print list_of_a
```

and get:

name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name
name

where i'm try make `query ("SELECT name FROM table")`

i get: value1,value2,value3....,etc from column "name"

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this.

```
query = ("SELECT '%s' FROM table")
```

It will work.